# pyOpenGL: memory issue using openvr with pyqt5 (HTC Vive)

Tags: qt5, python-3.7, pyopengl, openvr

we are developing a virtual environment using `qt5` and `pyopenvr` with the HTC Vive. All our scripts are fine and working. On one laptop, however, we all of a sudden keep having an issue.

It's a high-end gaming laptop equipped with a `gtx1060 (6gb)`, so it can't be a real memory problem. Even a complete system reboot with only the required installations and all drivers up to date didn't solve it. It used to work at one point when we first tested the laptop, but now this error keeps recurring:

```
GLError: GLError(
err = 1285,
description = b'Nicht gen\xfcgend Arbeitsspeicher',
baseOperation = glRenderbufferStorageMultisample,
cArguments = (
    GL_RENDERBUFFER,
    2,
    GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8,
    1512,
    1680,
))
```

"Nicht genügend Arbeitsspeicher" is the German equivalent for out of memory.
This happens even if we are running only the sample "hello world"-script of pyopenvr to show the simple color cube. The error is the same when using our scripts. On another laptop, everything works fine.

Anyone encountered a similar issue? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This could be a whole set of different issues from driver bug, to a bug in your code that only shows in certain cases.

I would advice that you debug it by different means, such as removing part of the code and seeing if you hit the same bug, or maybe you can break on error to inspect the data that is passed to the driver (is this possible in Python)?

You could also try using different versions of drivers, libraries etc.

Sorry for such a vague answer, but really there isn't much else I could advice from your question.